# How to extend TikZ drawing commands

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a carc path macro (centered arc, that acts like circle, without changing the current position) in a way to be able to write :

```
\draw (0,0) carc(30:90:1) carc(30:90:2) carc(30:90:3);
```

I know how to do it with latex macro :

```
\def\carc(#1:#2:#3){++(#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3) ++(#2+180:#3)}
```

and then I can use :

```
\draw (0,0) \carc(30:90:1) \carc(30:90:2) \carc(30:90:3);
```

But I'm wondering, if there is a way to do this in pure TikZ ?

Is it a way to create new macros that acts like circle, rectangle, arc, ... on paths ?

Comment: No, AFAIK not with hacking/rewriting parts of the parsing code of TikZ. That code is complicated and not meant to be extensible.

Comment: That's also why you might want to consider switching to Metapost;).

Comment: Alain Matthes has implemented something like this in `tkz-euclide`, which is built on TikZ. The centre needs to be a named `coordinate`/`node`. With `\usepackage{tkz-euclide} \usetkzobj{arcs}` in the preamble, and a node named `O`, you can write `\tkzDrawArc[R](O,2cm)(30,90)` in a `tikzpicture` to draw an arc with radius 2 cm from 30° to 90°.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution that works with

```
\draw (0,0) carc(30:90:1) carc(30:90:2) carc(30:90:3);
```

and allows full use of the standard options that `arc` takes.  It uses Jake's trick to extend the parser, but instead of inserting completely new code, we subvert the `arc` command to do it for us.  Essentially, we replace `carc` by `arc`, which means that `carc` can take all the arguments that `arc` does, but then when `arc` actually comes to add something to the path (after it has worked out all the coordinates) we sneak in a couple of movetos to ensure that the centre of the path is where we want it to be.  This will also work without subverting the parser simply by putting `[centre arc]` before calling `arc`.  (In fact, `carc` workds by expanding to `[centre arc] arc`.)

***I still strongly recommend the `to path` solution.  Do not subvert the TikZ code unless you know what you are doing.***

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34973/86}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@@@carcfinal#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@process{#2}%
  \advance\pgf@x by \tikz@lastx
  \advance\pgf@y by \tikz@lasty
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}%
  #1%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
  \let\tikz@@@arcfinal=\carc@orig@@@arcfinal
}

\def\tikz@carcfinal{%
  \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@lastx%
  \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@lasty%
  \let\tikz@arcfinal=\carc@orig@arcfinal
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}


\let\carc@orig@@@arcfinal=\tikz@@@arcfinal
\let\carc@orig@arcfinal=\tikz@arcfinal

\def\tikz@cchar{% If keyword starts with "c..."
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar i %... starts with "ci..."
        {\tikz@circle}%
        {\pgfutil@ifnextchar h% ... starts with "ch..."
            {\tikz@children}
            {\pgfutil@ifnextchar a % ... starts with "ca..."
                {\carc@call}
                \tikz@cochar
            }
        }
}%

\def\carc@call{\tikzset{centred arc}\tikz@scan@next@command}

\tikzset{
  centred arc/.code={%
    \let\tikz@@@arcfinal=\tikz@@@carcfinal
    \let\tikz@arcfinal=\tikz@carcfinal
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) carc[start angle=30,end angle=90,radius=1] carc (30:90:2) carc(30:90:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note the different syntax for the `carc`s and the varying number of spaces.

[image: Centred arcs]

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Jake ! This answers completely my questions.

Answer (score 20):

Martin is right, you need to rewrite parts of the parser. It's not very difficult, however. The parser lives in `tikz.code.tex`. There's a macro called `\tikz@cchar` which processes all keywords starting with `c`. It contains nested `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` statements that act as a "select" expression: They look at the next letter in the keyword and call the corresponding macro.

Here's the original `\tikz@cchar` definition:

```
\def\tikz@cchar{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar i{\tikz@circle}%
  {\pgfutil@ifnextchar h{\tikz@children}{\tikz@cochar}}}%
```

If the character following a `c` is an `i`, TikZ assumes you mean the `circle` keyword. If it is an `h`, it assumes you want a `child` in a tree. If it is neither, TikZ assumes you want either a `cosine` or a `coordinate`, so it passes control on to the `\tikz@cochar`, which then decides in a similar manner which of the two keywords are present.

To make the parser recognise `carc`, we can redefine the `\tikz@cchar` macro like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@cchar{% If keyword starts with "c..."
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar i %... starts with "ci..."
        {\tikz@circle}%
        {\pgfutil@ifnextchar h% ... starts with "ch..."
            {\tikz@children}
            {\pgfutil@ifnextchar a % ... starts with "ca..."
                {\carc}
                \tikz@cochar
            }
        }
}%
```

The `\carc` macro needs to be redefined slightly. The syntax isn't `\carc (#1:#2:#3)`, but rather `\carc arc (#1:#2:#3)`, since the initial `c` is the entity that actually calls the macro, and the `arc` is still present in the macro argument. Also, we can't use TikZ commands directly in the code (PGF commands would work). TikZ commands can be used by wrapping them in `\tikzset{insert path={<TikZ code>}}`, which directly inserts the desired code. Finally, we need to tell the TikZ parser to go back to looking for keywords by issuing a `\tikz@scan@next@command` at the end of the `\carc` macro.

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@cchar{% If keyword starts with "c..."
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar i %... starts with "ci..."
        {\tikz@circle}%
        {\pgfutil@ifnextchar h% ... starts with "ch..."
            {\tikz@children}
            {\pgfutil@ifnextchar a % ... starts with "ca..."
                {\carc}
                \tikz@cochar
            }
        }
}%

\def\carc arc (#1:#2:#3){% The macro will get called after the initial "c" of "carc" is already gobbled up, and only "arc" is left
    \tikzset{insert path={++(#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3) ++(#2+180:#3)}}% Inject the TikZ commands
    \tikz@scan@next@command% Return control to the parser
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (0,0) carc (30:90:1) carc (30:90:2) carc (30:90:3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake ! It works fine, with one exception : I have to put a white space between "carc" and "(", so `carc (30:90:1)` works, but `carc(30:90:1)` doesn't. Any idea ?

Comment: @Kpym: You can just say `\def\carc arc(#1:#2:#3){...` (without the whitespace).

Comment: Or you can have `\carc` have no arguments but simply swallow the `arc` and its following spaces and then call `\c@rc` which does the actual processing.

Comment: @Jake Yes but if I declare `\def\carc arc(#1:#2:#3){` I can't use it with space. The question is how to be able to use both ? 
And even better how to use carc[...] (...) like arc[...] (...) by passing the arguments to the arc macro ?

Comment: @Kpym: with the two stage macro then the first swallows whatever spaces are there in such a way that if there are none, it doesn't complain.  Then you can use it both with and without a space.

Comment: I have been able to solve the space problem by using declaration like this `\def\carc arc#1(#2:#3:#4)`. The #1 is just 0 or more spaces. But if I want to put arguments in #1 with `[...]` and the to use them in arc macro, it doesn't work ... any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 12):

Jake and Martin are right in that if you really absolutely must have

```
\draw (0,0) carc(30:90:1) carc(30:90:2) carc(30:90:3);
```

then your only option is to redefine the parser.

However, TikZ does have a standard way of defining quite general alternative paths without necessitating this heavy duty hacking.  It's the `to path` syntax.  A `to` path allows you to specify quite arbitrary code to replace the next bit of the path with something quite complicated.  You can [search the site for `to path`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+%22to+path%22) to get an idea of what's possible with this.

In your case, the code is quite simple.  It does have one sneaky bit: the target of a `to path` is saved unprocessed which means that we can interpret it how we like.  Instead of specifying a coordinate, we use it to specify the parameters for the `arc` command.  We therefore have to parse this data and split it according to how we're going to use it.  There are other ways to do this, but as we have to specify a target for a `to path`, we may as well use that as a way of passing information.

Here's the code.  I included your macro for comparison so that you can see that this does do the same.  I made two changes when translating your macro to a `to path`: I used the newer syntax for the `arc` command and I used the `\tikztostart` command when ensuring that we return to the place from whence we came.  Both are cosmetic changes designed to make the code clearer so that in 6 months time you can still understand what it's doing without having to puzzle it out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\carcArgs#1:#2:#3\carcSTOP{%
  \def\carcOne{#1}%
  \def\carcTwo{#2}%
  \def\carcThree{#3}%
}

\tikzset{
  centred arc/.style={%
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \expandafter\carcArgs\tikztotarget\carcSTOP
      }
      ++(\carcOne:\carcThree) arc[start angle=\carcOne, end angle=\carcTwo, radius=\carcThree] (\tikztostart)
    }
  }
}
\def\carc(#1:#2:#3){++(#1:#3) arc(#1:#2:#3) ++(#2+180:#3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) \carc(30:90:1) -- (2,-1);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,red]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) to[centred arc] (30:90:1) -- (2,-1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result, the black line is your macro and the red line is mine:

[image: Centred arcs]

Comment: This is a nice solution Andrew, but I was searching how to extend TikZ with carc path that works like core macro. The only thing that is missing for me in Jake's solution, is the possibility to put `[...]` arguments after carc. For me carc is really missing in TikZ.

Comment: @Kpym: I'm sure that everyone has their own list of things that are missing in TikZ *for them*.  That's why the `to path` is so useful: maximum flexibility combined with portability.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `carc` using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    insert path={+(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [carc=30:90:1] (0,0) [carc=30:90:2] (0,0) [carc=30:90:3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The API is slightly more complicated than yours: you must give the center coordinates for every arc separately.

You can also extend this to create semi-circles and quarter-circles, if you find you need them frequently, e.g.

```
\documentclass[class=article,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  carc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    insert path={+(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
  }
}

\tikzset{
  semicircle/.style args={#1:#2}{
    insert path={+(#1:#2) arc (#1:#1+180:#2)}
  }
}

\tikzset{
  quartercircle/.style args={#1:#2}{
    insert path={+(#1:#2) arc (#1:#1+90:#2)}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=2]
\draw [red] (0,0) [carc=30:90:1];
\draw [green!60!black] (0.25,0.25) [quartercircle=30:1];
\draw [blue] (0.5,0.5) [semicircle=30:1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I liked your answer rather, so I added a screenshot and extension for semi-circles and quarter-circles, which I find I need all the time. :-)